# Placing values into array of structs?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm having trouble putting values into my array of structs. With a single struct it works fine, however as soon as I make an array of them, I get a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error. I've run this code through a debugger and it says that the segfault is caused in `readFile` at `fseek(fp,0L,SEEK_END)`. if I remove the variables that has to do with any sort of memory allocation, the error simply shifts to the next variable in the line.

I'm pretty sure this has something to do with how I am trying to put values into the array of structs.

The struct:

```
struct parseData    {
    char rules[1000][1000];
    char depend[1000][1000];
    char commands[1000][1000];
};
```

The readFile method: (reads the file into a char[])

```
void readFile(){
        int res = 0;                
        fseek( fp , 0L , SEEK_END);
        malSize = ftell( fp );
        rewind( fp );

    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int j =0;
    char printError = 0;
    int lineNum = 0;
    char printFlag = 1;

    buffer = (char *)malloc(malSize * sizeof(char));

    res = isblank(*buffer);     
        while(fgets(buffer,malSize,fp)!=NULL){  
        strcpy(lines[i], buffer);
        lineNum++;
        
        if(feof(fp) ) {
            break;
        }
                        
        if(*lines[i] == '#' ){
            continue;
        } else if (strcmp(lines[i], "\n") == 0) {
           continue;
        }
        
    if(isblank(lines[i][0]) == 0){
        for(k;k<strlen(lines[i]);k++){
            if(lines[i][k] == ':'){
                printError =0;
                break;
            } else {
                printError =1;
            }
        }   
    }

    if(printError==1){
    fprintf(stderr,"Syntax error at line %d: Expected colon separator in rule header:\n", lineNum);
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    printFlag = 0;

    exit(1);        
} 

    
    if(printFlag){
        removeDoubleSpacing(buffer);
        rulesAndCommands();

    }
    i++;
  }
k=0;
}
```

the method that I am using to put the values that I need, into the struct array.

```
void rulesAndCommands(){
    struct parseData data[5000];
    int result = 0;
    static int count = 1;
    int each = 0;
    char *token = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    static char printed =0;
    int k =0;
    
    result = isblank(*buffer);

     if(result == 1){   
        if(printed == 0){
            printf("Commands:\n");
            printed =1;
        }
        
        printed++;
        printf("    %s",buffer);
    } else {
        for(token = strtok(buffer, ":"); token != NULL; token = strtok(NULL, ":")) {
            strcpy(data[j].rules[i],token);
            
           printf ( "Rule %d:\n", count);
            printf ( "    Targets: %s\n",data[j].rules[i]);
            printf ( "    Dependencies: ") ; 
            
            each = 0;
            printed = 0;
            i++;
            while ( ( token = strtok ( NULL, " ")) != NULL) {
                strcpy(data[j].depend[i],token);

                    
                if (each) {
                    printf ( ",");
                }
                
                 printf ( " %s",data[j].depend[k]);
                each++;
                k++; 
            }
            
            printf ( "\n");
        
         } 
        count++;
        j++;

    }

}
```

I realise this code is really rough, I'm just trying to get a working model before cleaning it up.

Comment: Why do you only access `data[x].depend[x]` when your `depend` has two dimensions? I mean, thats not your issue, but methinks that may be unintended.

Comment: Sizeof `parseData` is 3MB. `struct parseData data[5000]` trys to get 15GB from your stack. Do you have enough RAM?

Answer (score 0):

If the error is in `fseek(fp,0L,SEEK_END);` you probably haven't opened the file or an error occurred when you open the file.

Did you check the return from `fp=fopen(...);` wasn't `NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

```
struct parseData {
    char rules[1000][1000];
    char depend[1000][1000];
    char commands[1000][1000];
};

struct parseData data[5000];
```

`parseData` need 3MB for these 3 2-dimensional arrays, so `data` needs 15GB of memory. This is way above stack limit (usually about 10MB or 100MB depending on compiler). Your code suggests the arrays can be reduced as follows:

```
struct parseData 
{
    char rules[1000][50];
    char depend[1000][50];
};
...
struct parseData data[1000];
```

`data` will still need 100MB of memory, which is probably still over stack limit. Therefore you should declare `data` on heap.

```
struct parseData data[1000];
int main()
{
    ...
}
```

You can also write a small test program for using `realloc`, this allows you to increase the amount the memory during run time, so you won't need a huge buffer.